# Javascript image swap isn't working

Tags: javascript, image, src

This is the first thing I have ever tried to make in javascript and I'm not sure why it isn't working. The goal is to simply swap images back and forth on a click event. I'm wondering if it is an issue with my relative links not working. I copied the code directly from another answer I found on this website so the error is probably very minor.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function swap248(){
        if(document.getElementById("normal248").src=="images/248img1.png"){
            document.getElementById("normal248").src="images/248img2.png";  
        }else if(document.getElementById("normal248").src=="images/248img2.png"){
            document.getElementById("normal248").src = "images/248img1.png";
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="normal248" onclick="swap248()" src="images/248img1.png" width="294" height="461" alt=""/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the web browser console say?

Comment: The `src` property, when read, always gives the full URL of the image, so it will never be something like `images/248img2.png`. Instead, it will be `http://www.example.com/image/248img2.png`.

Comment: If you want the `src` as it is specified in the HTML, you should probably use `getAttribute('src')` and `setAttribute('src', 'images/248img2.png')`.  But i think what you really want is to keep track of the toggle state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` property read full URL. Instead, you can maintain a variable to swap between two images.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isFirstImage = true; // by default first image is shown
    function swap248(){
        if(isFirstImage){ // shows second image
        document.getElementById("normal248").src = "images/248img1.png";
        isFirstImage = false;
        } else { // shows first image
        document.getElementById("normal248").src="images/248img2.png";
        isFirstImage = true;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="normal248" onclick="swap248()" src="images/248img1.png" width="294" height="461"  alt=""/>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE** : Its only for very basic level. If you have several images to swap, you can maintain it in `data`(instead of variable) attribute of element which image is currently visible.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work on the first click for me though. I'm sure its because the second image needs to load but is there a way to prepare the function before it is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use css to swap an image

in that case you don't even need javascript.

if you want i can show you an example ...

else if you want to use javascript here is your function but a little shorter

Assuming that your default image is `images/248img1.png`

```
function swap248() {
  var a = document.getElementById("normal248");
  a.x = '248img2' == a.x ? '248img1' : '248img2'; // short if
  a.src ='images/' + a.x + '.png';
}
```

**How does this work?**

Every element in javascriptis an object.

So you can add variables to this object.

In this case the first check fails as x is undefined.

and so it returns false and gives you the second image.

in the next check x is set to the second image and it returns the first one..

remove 'enter code here' after `</html>`

Comment: How could one use CSS to swap an `<img>` src on *click*?

Comment: background & target no need for onclick event **or** postion using a sprite effect.

Comment: But the `:target` pseudo class doesn't make it stay… Also, `background` is for background things only, not very semantic. You'd rather have two `<img>` elements which are shown alternately.

Comment: depends on how he uses the page .. if he has other targets then it won't work.. for a simple example it would work.. to swap 2 images ... especially if they are the same size i use almost always sprite effects using background changing class or position.which is 99% the best way. in that caseyou need js just to toggle the class.it could also be triggered from parent classes...

Comment: it always depends how you wanna do things.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to test the last part of the url like this :

```
function swap248(){
    if(document.getElementById("normal248").src.match(/images\/248img1.png$/g){
        document.getElementById("normal248").src="images/248img2.png";  
    }else if(document.getElementById("normal248").src.match(/images\/248img2.png$/g){
        document.getElementById("normal248").src = "images/248img1.png";
    }
}
```

Caution : You need to escape the `/` character in the match pattern.

and add a `$` at the end to verify it's the end of the src. (ie :`.match(/images\/248img2.png$/g)`)

**EDIT :**

You can try : `.match(/t\/[0-9]{3}img1.png$/g)`

`[0-9]` means you are searching for numbers and `{3}` means the string must have 3 numbers before "img1" to match.

Comment: Fascinating! Thanks. So what is the function of the 'g' character at the end of the match?

Comment: It's for "insensitive case", and my solution works with more than 2 images ! :)

Comment: Is there a way I can make your function automatically work for more than 2 images? Like instead of searching for "248img1.png" it could search for "[3 digit number passed into the function from the image's filename]img1.png"? 248 stands for a suite number in a building and it would be nice to not iterate the function for every other suite. I know its probably elementary but I'm learning a ton right now!